# JSON error when request PHP file link

Tags: javascript, php, android, json, web-services

when i request php file using HttpURLConnection as the following

```
link = "http://mastermaster.0fees.us/signup.php";
URL url = new URL(link); 
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

i receives a json file with a message in the end of it that told **this site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript**

when i test the link in my laptop it works fine, so what should i do, the full requesting code is as the following;

```
try {
    data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
    data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
    data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
    data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
    data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");
    link = "http://mastermaster.0fees.us/signup.php"+data;
    URL url = new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    result = bufferedReader.readLine();

    return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be able to get around it by setting a user-agent and / or a cookie jar. But, it very much depends on what the remote site is doing.

Comment: I tried to check your code, I got 403 Forbidden from the URL you gave.

Comment: may you give my code lines so add them to my code and test that

Comment: try it again:                                           http://mastermaster.0fees.us/signup.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the `__test` cookie from a previous request and then pass it to the next one.

I did a quick test in PHP and it worked:

```
{"query_result":"done"}
```

Comment: i am rellay sorry but i cant understand you may you say it in more simple way.  great thanx to your help

Comment: @user3498298 You need to 1) do a request to `http://mastermaster.0fees.us/` and save the `__test` cookie from the response 2) use that cookie in your request to `http://mastermaster.0fees.us/signup.php`

Comment: can you make it as acode to add it to the code above in my question

Comment: @user3498298 Sorry, I can't, I'm not familiar with `HttpURLConnection`. Can't you just disable the JavaScript detection since that URL seems to be under your control?

Comment: i dont know if i can cause i dont know if there is any way to do it :(